# Microsoft Visual Studio Tests - Successful Individually, Failing as Group

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests

I've been working on some automation code that includes about 65 small tests. All 65 tests can be ran successfully individually. However, once we run the tests all together - they seem to fail. Once one tests fails, they all seem to fail after that. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Is there something happening in the transition of one failing test to the next which will automatically make the next one fail?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you've got some state leaking between tests. Are you sure each one leaves the environment how they found it?

Comment: could you post the code + the output ? the are a myriad of reasons for such an outcome and the question is a tad vague.

Comment: It might not be state - if they are running in parallel, and the code is not thread-safe, you could receive similar behaviour...

Comment: I think there may be state leaks between tests. Currently adjusting the tests/... Thank you